# When I try to load audio and images from the API into the media player and image view in ViewPager2, they do not appear in the order they were loaded

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, android-adapter, android-viewpager2

When I try to load audio and images from the API into ViewPager2's media player and image view, they don't load in the correct order; audio is sometimes different from their image and text when loaded in ViewPager2 (for example, if I slide down or up, music is different from their order, but image and text are in their order).

Watch this video for a better explanation. "[Video Url](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jM7fA2bG6ZHL_oNm-vDYOoP9f5bwwtuP/view?usp=share_link)"

So I want to create a feature similar to Resso Music App (sliding up and down to change music, similar to how we change videos on TikTok).

For this functionality, I use ViewPager2, an array list, an adapter, and Retrofit.

**MusicFragment.java**

```
public class MusicFragment extends Fragment {
    View v;
    List<AllMusicModel.Data> musicItems;
    ViewPager2 musicsViewPager;
    private MusicAdapter musicAdapter;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_music, container, false);
        musicsViewPager = v.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerVideos);
        musicsViewPager.setUserInputEnabled(true);
        musicItems = new ArrayList<>();
        musicAdapter = new MusicAdapter(getActivity(), musicItems);
        musicsViewPager.setAdapter(musicAdapter);
        call_music_list_api();
        return v;
    }

    private void call_music_list_api() {

        // Api implementation
        String Token = "Bearer " + Config.getToken(requireContext());
        String APIChannel = "App";
        String AppVersion = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
        Call<AllMusicModel> mCall = RetrofitClient.getAdapter().GetAllMusic(APIChannel, AppVersion, Token);
        mCall.enqueue(new Callback<AllMusicModel>() {
            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<AllMusicModel> call, @NonNull Response<AllMusicModel> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    AllMusicModel alldata = response.body();

                    String code;
//                    String message;
                    String status;

                    if (alldata != null) {
                        code = String.valueOf(alldata.getStatuscode());
//                        message = String.valueOf(alldata.getMessage());
                        status = String.valueOf(alldata.getStatus());
                        if (code.equals("200")) {
                            musicItems.clear();
                            musicItems.addAll(alldata.getData());
                            musicAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } else if (Objects.equals(code, "401")) {
                            Log.e("MusicFragment", "onResponse: " + status);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<AllMusicModel> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Error", String.valueOf(t));

            }
        });
    }

}
```

**fragment_music.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/parent.contentLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:context=".Fragments.MusicFragment">
        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerVideos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**MusicAdapter.java**

```
public class MusicAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MusicAdapter.MusicViewHolder> {
    private final Context context;
    private final List<AllMusicModel.Data> mMusiclist;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    public MusicAdapter(Context context, List<AllMusicModel.Data> musicItems) {
        this.context = context;
        mMusiclist = musicItems;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MusicViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MusicViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.music_layout, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MusicViewHolder holder, int position) {
       final MusicViewHolder finalholder = holder;
        finalholder.setMusicData(mMusiclist.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mMusiclist.size();
    }

    class MusicViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView mImageView, play_pause_image;
        TextView txtTitle, txtDesc;
        ProgressBar mProgressBar;
        ConstraintLayout play_pause_layout, linearLayout;

        public MusicViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            txtTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            txtDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);
            mProgressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            play_pause_layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.play_pause_layout);
            play_pause_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.play_pause_image);
            linearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        }

        void setMusicData(AllMusicModel.Data musicItem) {

            txtTitle.setText(musicItem.getTitle());
//            txtDesc.setText(musicItem);
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }
            mImageView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    //stop or pause your media player mediaPlayer.stop(); or mediaPlayer.pause();
                    play_pause_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    play_pause_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_round_play);
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    play_pause_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    play_pause_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_round_pause);
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(() -> play_pause_layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE), 4000);
                }
            });

            String audioUrl = ApiUrls.Api_LocalHost_Url + musicItem.getAudio();
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioUrl);
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mediaPlayer -> {
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(MediaPlayer::start);
            String imageUrl = ApiUrls.Api_LocalHost_Url + musicItem.getImage();
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(imageUrl)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .error(R.drawable.loading)
                    .into(mImageView);

        }
    }
}
```

**music_layout.xml** (Layout for Load Adater Data)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/contentBodyColor"
  >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/play_pause_layout"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@drawable/music_play_pause_bg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/play_pause_image"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/back_button"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_round_play"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="15"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDesc"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="15"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**AllMusicModel.java**

```
public class AllMusicModel {

    @SerializedName("statuscode")
    @Expose
    private Integer statuscode;
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<Data> data = null;

    public Integer getStatuscode() {
        return statuscode;
    }

    public void setStatuscode(Integer statuscode) {
        this.statuscode = statuscode;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public List<Data> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Data> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public class Data {

        @SerializedName("id")
        @Expose
        private Integer id;
        @SerializedName("title")
        @Expose
        private String title;
        @SerializedName("image")
        @Expose
        private String image;
        @SerializedName("audio")
        @Expose
        private String audio;
        @SerializedName("time")
        @Expose
        private String time;
        @SerializedName("status")
        @Expose
        private String status;
        @SerializedName("createdAt")
        @Expose
        private String createdAt;
        @SerializedName("updatedAt")
        @Expose
        private String updatedAt;

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public void setImage(String image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        public String getAudio() {
            return audio;
        }

        public void setAudio(String audio) {
            this.audio = audio;
        }

        public String getTime() {
            return time;
        }

        public void setTime(String time) {
            this.time = time;
        }

        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public String getCreatedAt() {
            return createdAt;
        }

        public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
            this.createdAt = createdAt;
        }

        public String getUpdatedAt() {
            return updatedAt;
        }

        public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt) {
            this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
        }

    }
}
```

Json Response From API

```
{"statuscode":200,"status":"Success","message":"Music List","data":[{"id":6,"title":"Faded","image":"1156127.jpg","audio":"waha.mp3","time":"Testing","status":"Testing","createdAt":"2022-10-05T20:36:56.000Z","updatedAt":"2022-10-05T20:36:56.000Z"},{"id":7,"title":"Drive Forever","image":"driveforever.jpg","audio":"driveforever.mp3","time":"Testing","status":"Testing","createdAt":"2022-10-05T20:46:51.000Z","updatedAt":"2022-10-05T20:46:51.000Z"}]}
```

Comment: try by initializing mediaPlayer into the MusicViewHolder constructor and manage the rest of the mediaPlayer operation accordingly. This might help you. And try to write clean code :) Happy Coding

Comment: @DineshSarma Do you mean like this?

class MusicViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

Comment: public MusicViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            .....
        }
here inside the constructor

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @DineshSarma Thank you, I'm working on it and will let you know how it goes.